# how to select element of div dropdown in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i'm trying to get the div element from a dropdown but haven't been able to get the desire result.

i have tried action class and select class

This is my  code:

```
<div class="ant-select-selection
            ant-select-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0"><div class="ant-select-selection__rendered"><div class="ant-select-selection-selected-value" title="Student" style="display: block; opacity: 1;">Student</div></div><span class="ant-select-arrow" unselectable="unselectable" style="user-select: none;"><b></b></span></div>
```

This is my webdriver script:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ant-select-selection-selected-value']")).click();        
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div/div"));
    Actions action= new Actions(driver);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5 ,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        action.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
```

element should be selected, but haven't get the result  nor get any error message

Comment: Are you trying to select another value on the dropdown? Or do you want to get the selected value?  The HTML you have provided is not enough to reach any solution. This HTML doesn't contain the list of data that the dropdown can select. Can you provide the page link or source of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Dmitri T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2897748/dmitri-t) mentioned, always try to use relative XPath instead of absolute XPath.

Your code is not working most probably for the absolute XPath is invalid.

Also, use explicit waits instead of implicit waits. The list is present in the DOM always but it is only visible and clickable when you click on the dropdown field.

Try this:

```java
driver.get("https://goodprofbadprof.com/search-school");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='form-group']/label[contains(text(),'Search By')]/following-sibling::div")).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//ul[@role='menu']/li[contains(text(),'State')]"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use [relative XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) as your absolute value:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div/div
```

- doesn't look good
- is very fragile and sensitive to any DOM change

So I would suggest considering either using [`title` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_title.asp) like:

```
//div[@title='Student']
```

or the [`div` element](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp) text. In this case it's better to use [XPath `contains()` function](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) as your text seems to have line breaks

```
//div[contains(@text(), 'Student')]
```

Comment: thanks Dmitri..I have tried relative path as well, but it shows error that "unable to locate element". might be the reason is that this element is loaded dynamically..